# Rails Tutorial error: "Validation failed: Email has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I got as far as Listing 9.28. in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and I am getting the following errors when running `bundle exec rspec spec/`. I am not sure how to clear these errors.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
................................................FF...........FFFFFFFF

Failures:

  1) User pages index profile page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages index profile page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages index edit page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User pages index edit page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User pages index edit page 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User pages index edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User pages index edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) User pages index edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) User pages index edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) User pages index edit with valid information 
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Email has already been taken
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:95:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:97:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 7.29 seconds
69 examples, 10 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:31 # User pages index profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:32 # User pages index profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:102 # User pages index edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:103 # User pages index edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:104 # User pages index edit page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:118 # User pages index edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:119 # User pages index edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:120 # User pages index edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:121 # User pages index edit with valid information 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:122 # User pages index edit with valid information
```

My user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }


describe "index" do
    before do
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
      FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: "Ben", email: "ben@example.com")
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'All users') }


    it "should list each user" do
      User.all.each do |user|
        page.should have_selector('li', text: user.name)
      end

end

describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
end


describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end

 describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end

      describe "error messages" do
        before { click_button submit }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
        it { should have_content('error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end

      describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }

        let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }

        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
        it { should have_link('Sign out') }

      end
    end
  end

  describe "edit" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in user
      visit edit_user_path(user)
    end

    describe "page" do
      it { should have_selector('h1',    text: "Update your profile") }
      it { should have_selector('title', text: "Edit user") }
      it { should have_link('change', href: 'http://gravatar.com/emails') }
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:new_name)  { "New Name" }
      let(:new_email) { "new@example.com" }
      before do
        fill_in "Name",             with: new_name
        fill_in "Email",            with: new_email
        fill_in "Password",         with: user.password
        fill_in "Confirm Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Save changes"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: new_name) }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success') }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      specify { user.reload.name.should  == new_name }
      specify { user.reload.email.should == new_email }
    end
    end


  end
end
```

My spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb Looks like this:

```
    require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }

  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
    before { click_button "Sign in" }

    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
    #it { should have_selector('div.flash.error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.flash.error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

      it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { Factory(:user) }

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { put user_path(user) }
          specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "visiting user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          #it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
        end

      end
    end

    describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
        before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My users.controller.rb looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

sessions.helper.rb:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
  end
```

header.html.erb:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", users_path %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Probably best if you post your Github repo for others to run your tests.  Looking at your error message though, have you put all your tests inside the `describe "index" do` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the structure of your user_pages_spec.rb with mhartl's [original](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app/blob/master/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb). You have definitely misplaced some `end`'s because the `describe "profile page" do` and `describe "edit" do` blocks are embedded in your `describe "index" do` block when they shouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. I had the ends misplaced. Thanks for the link to the original so i could compare.